# installing tk in ruby

Tags: ruby, rvm, tk-toolkit

On my Kubuntu 17.04 System I installed ruby via rvm:
`rvm install ruby-2.4.2`

After that I got aware that I needed tk too. I did `rvm reinstall 2.4.2 --enable-shared --enable-pthread --with-tk --with-tcl`

But still if I `require "tk"` in irb, I get:

```
2.4.2 :001 > require "tk"
LoadError: cannot load such file -- tk
    from /home/karsten/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.2/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.4.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /home/karsten/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.2/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.4.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from (irb):1
    from /home/karsten/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.2/bin/irb:11:in `<main>`
```

I installed libtcltk-ruby via `sudo apt-get install libtcltk-ruby`.

Now I'm stuck. What am I doing wrong and how to fix it?

Comment: I have installed with `gem install tk`.

Comment: I allready tried this, it says `Warning:: cannot find Tcl library. tcltklib will not be compiled (tcltklib is disabled on your Ruby. That is, Ruby/Tk will not work). Please check configure options.` and `Can't find proper Tcl/Tk libraries. So, can't make tcltklib.so which is required by Ruby/Tk.
If you have Tcl/Tk libraries on your environment, you may be able to use them with configure options (see ext/tk/README.tcltklib).
At present, Tcl/Tk8.6 is not supported. Although you can try to use Tcl/Tk8.6 with configure options, it will not work correctly. I recommend you to use Tcl/Tk8.5 or 8.4`

Comment: BTW: I already removed Tcl/Tk8.6 and installed 8.5

Answer (score 0):

The version of libtcltk is probably not the same. In ubuntu 16.04 it is 2.3.1.
I de-installed rvm and loaded the package: sudo apt install ruby-full. libtcltk is then included.

Comment: This should go into comment section